# Http response code enums in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking for something like `HttpResponseCode::FileNotFound` => 404, `HttpResponseCode::OK` => 200

I've searched for "php http status codes list", "php http status codes enum" and couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The term to search for is "php http status codes const" which leads you to http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-using-constants-for-http-status-code - It has `\Illuminate\Http\Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND` and `\Illuminate\Http\Response::HTTP_OK`

etc.

List is here - https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Response.php

Comment: Exactly what I needed and couldn't remember where it was it. Thanks!